# ROS 2 Humble packages absolutely required when building from source

Tags: ros-humble

When building ROS2 Humble from source there are over 300 packages that need to be built when you follow the official instructions.

Are all of these packages required to run ROS2 Humble? Can I cut this list down and still run ros2 humble?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the package requirements for the core and base variants at

https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2001.html

There's some context and discussion here

https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/issues/870

and here

https://discourse.ros.org/t/core-base-and-desktop-releases/20267/2

that might help you set up a minimal source install.